# Reactive Form Validation errors not displaying in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on Angular 5 applications, I wanted to display the follow error message based on user inputs

```
emptyUserName = 'You must enter a username';
minlengthUserName = 'User name must be at least 3 characters long';
maxlengthUserName = 'Username cannot exceed 20 characters';
userNamePattern = 'Username should be in alphanumeric only';
```

But the issue is only, `emptyUserName` works others doesn't work and no errors in console also.

Below is my component code

```
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
        userName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)]),
        password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
```

Below is my Template code,

```
 <form class="ro-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="labelHead" for="username">
            <b>Username</b>
          </label>
          <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="userName" placeholder="username">

          <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.touched && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.required" class="form-error-messages"
            id="error-no-username">
            {{emptyUserName}}
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.touched && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.minLength" class="form-error-messages"
            id="error-minlength-username">
            {{minlengthUserName}}
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.touched && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.maxLength" class="form-error-messages"
            id="error-maxlength-username">
            {{maxlengthUserName}}
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.touched && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.pattern" class="form-error-messages"
            id="error-pattern-username">
            {{userNamePattern}}
          </div>
        </div>
```

What I'm doing wrong here ? Please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few glitches in your code first I would say replace `.touched` to `.dirty` to show form errors on the fly in template.

For max, min length error messages angular form doesnt have camelCase pattern, its simple all lowercase so use `minlength` and `maxlength` instead.

The complete template would look like.

```
<form class="ro-form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin()" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="labelHead" for="username">
        <b>Username</b>
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="userName" placeholder="username">

      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.dirty && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.required" class="form-error-messages"
        id="error-no-username">
        {{emptyUserName}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.dirty && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.minlength" class="form-error-messages"
        id="error-minlength-username">
        {{minlengthUserName}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.dirty && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.maxlength" class="form-error-messages"
        id="error-maxlength-username">
        {{maxlengthUserName}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.userName.dirty && loginForm.controls.userName.errors?.pattern" class="form-error-messages"
        id="error-pattern-username">
        {{userNamePattern}}
      </div>

      {{loginForm.controls.userName.errors | json}} <!-- see errors while typing the input -->
    </div>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xfdqpx)

Answer (score 1):

Change minLength to minlength and maxLength to maxlength in ngIf. For pattern error use customize validator or just use error.invalid value with message e. g: Form value has invalid format.